# Linux machines not recognized by Volatility

Tags: linux, memory

I am Using Volatility 2.6 On both windows7 and Kali Linux(latest version),

And my memory dumps are in “.vmem” from Vmware workstation and “.vmss”

I want to check linux base memories, by default volatility has no Linux profile so I’ve downloaded them and add them in
`…/volatility/plugins/overlays/linux`

Now I can see all of them in –info results under profiles list.
I have no problem with windows base memories but when I want to open for example an Ubuntu1204 or Ubuntu1404server I face the error that says:

`No suitable address space mapping found`

So finally I used `imageinfo` like this to find the profile automatically:
`Python vol.py  –f /mymemory.vmem imageinfo`
But again I face this error in kali linux: (and same errors in windows and the same result in older versions older volatility)

```
Volatility Foundation Volatility Framework 2.6
INFO    : volatility.debug    : Determining profile based on KDBG search...
WARNING : volatility.debug    : Overlay structure cpuinfo_x86 not present in vtypes
WARNING : volatility.debug    : Overlay structure cpuinfo_x86 not present in vtypes
WARNING : volatility.debug    : Overlay structure tty_struct not present in vtypes
WARNING : volatility.debug    : Overlay structure cpuinfo_x86 not present in vtypes
WARNING : volatility.debug    : Overlay structure tty_struct not present in vtypes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/volatility", line 192, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/volatility", line 183, in main
    command.execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/volatility/commands.py", line 145, in execute
    func(outfd, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/volatility/plugins/imageinfo.py", line 45, in render_text
    for k, t, v in data:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/volatility/plugins/imageinfo.py", line 55, in calculate
    suglist = [ s for s, _ in kdbgscan.KDBGScan.calculate(self)]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/volatility/plugins/kdbgscan.py", line 116, in calculate
    buf = addrspace.BufferAddressSpace(self._config)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/volatility/addrspace.py", line 378, in __init__
    BaseAddressSpace.__init__(self, None, config, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/volatility/addrspace.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.profile = self._set_profile(config.PROFILE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/volatility/addrspace.py", line 98, in _set_profile
    ret = profs[profile_name]()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/volatility/plugins/overlays/linux/linux.py", line 214, in __init__
    obj.Profile.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/volatility/obj.py", line 859, in __init__
    self.reset()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/volatility/plugins/overlays/linux/linux.py", line 224, in reset
    self.load_vtypes()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/volatility/plugins/overlays/linux/linux.py", line 261, in load_vtypes
    vtypesvar = dwarf.DWARFParser(dwarfdata).finalize()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/volatility/dwarf.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.feed_line(line)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/volatility/dwarf.py", line 162, in feed_line
    self.process_statement(**parsed) #pylint: disable-msg=W0142
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/volatility/dwarf.py", line 225, in process_statement
    self.id_to_name[statement_id] = [self.base_type_name(data)]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/volatility/dwarf.py", line 125, in base_type_name
    return self.tp2vol[data['DW_AT_name'].strip('"')]
KeyError: 'device_attribute'
```